# Where did the diatonic scales come from?

Tags: overtones

I was wondering how the diatonic scales came about? Like the major scale for instance, what is the reasoning of chosig just those notes? I've heard that the pentatonik scale comes from the overtone series, is it the same for the diatonic scales?